# Grouping in Anomaly Detection in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate, anomaly-detection

I have been trying to do anomaly detection using the `anomalize` package.

The problem I face is with grouping variables. If there is only column with one distinct value I could be able to run the anomaly detection but if there is multiple time series involved with more than one grouping variable it ends up failing.
Here I have two grouping variables- `Product` and `Location` and I tried grouping the data by `Product` and `Location` and converted to a `tibble` object but when i pass the `glimpse` function it is still not identifying the groups.
I have attached a sample code, if anyone could please help me with this that would be really helpful.

```
Test.df2 <-
structure(list(Product = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1"), Location = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", 
"C"), Period = c("Sep 2017", "Oct 2017", "Nov 2017", "Dec 2017", 
"Sep 2017", "Oct 2017", "Nov 2017", "Dec 2017"), Units = c(5.399993, 
9, 10, 9, 5, 1, 3, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")

Test.df2$Period<-lubridate::my(Test.df2$Period)
Test.df2[is.na(Test.df2)]<-0
Test.df2<-Test.df2 %>% group_by(Product,Location)
Test.df2<-as_tibble(Test.df2)
glimpse(Test.df2)
Test.df2.anomaly<- Test.df2 %>% 
  time_decompose(Units,merge = T,method = 'stl',frequency = "auto",
                 trend = "auto")%>%
  anomalize(remainder,method = 'gesd',alpha = 0.05,max_anoms = 0.2) %>%
  time_recompose()
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `series is not periodic or has less than two periods`, can you post a bigger data set?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of grouping the data.frame, and reassigning it to itself, group *in* the pipe.
The code below seems to be working, the problem is in the posted data.

```
library(anomalize)
library(dplyr)

str(Test.df2)

Test.df2 %>% 
  mutate(Period = lubridate::my(Period)) %>%
  group_by(Product, Location) %>%
  time_decompose(
    Units, 
    merge = TRUE,
    method = 'stl',
    frequency = "auto",
    trend = "auto"
  )%>%
  anomalize(
    remainder, 
    method = 'gesd',
    alpha = 0.05,
    max_anoms = 0.2
  ) %>%
  time_recompose()
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `nested.col`.
> ℹ `nested.col = purrr::map(.x = data, .f = .f, target = Units, ...)`.
> x series is not periodic or has less than two periods
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Thank you. But when i apply the mutate function, this is the error i get-Error in lapply(list(...), .num_to_date) : object 'Period' not found

Comment: @ArvindMenon You get that error when running the code in my answer with the data posted in the question? I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: The problem with my code I have used as.tibble after grouping the data frame which in turn un groups the data...so if I remove the as.tibble it is working...Seems like it is already a tibble object